# Gong drag and drop: drag effect border does not fit element

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

Using the gong drag and drop framework, one gets a drag effect, which is a simple border around the possible droptarget.

However, in my case for some reason this border doesn't fit the actual element, as shown here:
[image]

I have already tried to change background colors of the different xaml elements of the drop target to find out if some elements are bigger (but hidden), but couldn't find any.

I guess the problem is due to the usage of viewboxes, which I use, since the size of these drop targets is dynamic and zoom-able.

Here is the xaml code of drop target:

```
<Border BorderThickness="{Binding PlatformBorderThickness}"  dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{StaticResource CustomDropHandler}" >
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" >
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.9"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.9"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Equipment.Name, FallbackValue='Please add a device!'}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Stretch="Uniform"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button  Command="{Binding DeleteButtonClick}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
            Margin="0" Padding="0">
                <Image Source="/Resources/Cancel.ico"/>
            </Button>
        </Viewbox>

        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="2">
        <DataGrid Width="200" Height="135" HeadersVisibility="None" RowBackground="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Equipment.Settings}" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  GotFocus="DataGrid_GotFocus" Name="DutInfoGrid" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Equipment.ImagePath, FallbackValue={StaticResource AddItemImage}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource AddItemImage}}"
                                Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </DataGrid.Background>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="DutInfoGridRemoveButton" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" Height="15"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveClick, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <Image Source="/Resources/Trash.ico"/>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Items[3].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Items[6].Value}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**Edit:**

After some further testing I found out that if I remove the ViewBox element around the datagrid, the problem is gone. Any ideas, why the ViewBox causes this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: It does not make sense to wrap every control into a Viewbox. For instance Button by default stretches to occupy all available space. Proper dimension attributes and the proper panel will be enough to get a responsive layout. Don't wrap everything into a Viewbox.

Comment: @BionicCode you are probably right about the ViewBox around the button, however I have tried several configurations of how to wrap the controls into ViewBoxes (from using none at all to wrapping the whole border into a single one) and wrapping every control into it's own ViewBox was the only one, that gave the desired behaviour. This is due to the fact, that everything can be resized during runtime by the user and it is also zoomable. Anyway the ViewBox making problems is the one wrapping the datagrid and here the question, what causes this behaviour,  remains.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the it's a bug in the `GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop` NuGet.

Most probably it's in `OnRender` in file `DropTargetHighlightAdorner` - [link to source code](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop/blob/main/src/GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop/DropTargetHighlightAdorner.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably switch to the action file, then swap and use jQuery with the XML code which will refer to the drag and drop.